# Import default with alias

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

I would like to import a `default export`ed store with an `alias` using the syntax `import XXX as A from YYY`.

I know it works with this set up:

```
class XXX extends Reflux.Store{...}
export XXX;

//In another class you import:
import {XXX as ABC} from YYY;
```

That works great, but using that syntax with **export default** no longer works.

```
export default class XXX extends Reflux.Store{...}

//In another class you import:
import {XXX as ABC} from YYY;
```

But I know that if you **export default** you can't use **{}** syntax. Problem is that to use **import as** you need **{}**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is import it with the name you want to use it with. There is no need to use the same name that was given to the module exported by default, you can use any name to import it

```
import ABC from 'YYY'; // syntax for default import
```

which is the short for

```
import  { default as ABC } from 'YYY'
```

Comment: Most excellent! I'm an idiot, thank you for the explanation! :)

Comment: Glad to have helped